# how to enable passwordless ssh for a particular program only

Tags: c++, linux, ssh

I have a requirement where I want that user of my C++ program is able to do passwordless "ssh" on to a particular machine but the same user should not be able to do ssh on the same machine through a normal terminal/shell.

Comment: Do you mean you want to compile the password into the program?

Comment: No, I need some generic method which I can be embedded in my program so that ssh is not allowed generically but my program can do ssh.

Comment: SSH was designed to be secure, which means that some secret (passphrase, private key) must be present and must be managed securely. You want to turn the thing upside down and basically make security void. This doesn't make sense, so your question has no answer (especially after you have denied dan3's answer which is the *only* solution in your case).

Comment: What I want I that when user runs my program then I run some script internally which can do ssh setup so that program is able to do passwordless ssh on to that remote machine, but unnecessarily user is not able to log on to the remote machine, so that he is not able to launch some unauthorized program on that machine. now in this whole flow, where I am I making the basic security feature of ssh void?

Comment: The whole idea is flawed -- the application on the computer system can't (technically) have more rights than the individual who owns the computer system. You might find it a better idea to employ some custom protocol instead of SSH.

Comment: SO is not a forum and not a discussion board. It's for concrete and practical technical questions. For discussing your architecture you should find some developer forum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Match User stack
    ForceCommand exectute_me.sh
```

Suppose your user name is `stack`. In that case, put above lines in `sshd_config`.
So if this user (`stack`) try to login the server via `ssh`, the script called `execute_me.sh` will get executed.

If you are able to write some conditions specific for this user in `execute_me.sh`, I think you can do what you want with this user.

Answer (score 1):

use a proxy-program that is executed under a different UID (which is allowed to ssh to you remote host), and forward any requests from your real program to the proxy.

Comment: No that is not an option, as I need to do ssh on to remote machine through my program only through that user's id

Comment: if this is a follow-up to [your old question](stackoverflow.com/questions/10859863) you might want to consider using alternative IPC-mechanisms; (e.g. something as simple as opening a network socket on host1 and send a special token from host2 to that port)

Answer (score 0):

Hard-code the SSH password in your program (presumably obfuscated a little, though that doesn't help much).

Alternatively, use an [SSH key](http://paulkeck.com/ssh/) with a passphrase, and hardcode the key's passphrase (which is not the same thing as the Unix password) in the program (which gives you a little more control).

Are you sure you can't live with the user entering the SSH key passphrase ONCE at the beginning of each session (e.g. in the morning)? Every further ssh request will not need a password.

Comment: Paraphrase cant be hardcoded, as there can be any number of random users of my program.

Comment: Then store passwords or passphrases for users in a file. It's a further security breach, but that's what you get

Comment: No, I need to do every thing with minimum user input and if user would be doing ssh after entering the paraphrase then he can do independently outside my program as well, which I don't want.